# eclipse, remote systems explorer, custom commands

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm on windows machine and using Eclipse to edit some files on UNIX remote. I use Remote System Explorer to browse files over SSH which works superb (comparing with N++ explorer it's a rocket). Now the UNIX files are under ClearCase versioning and I'd like to have some "right click" options in Eclipse's Remote System Explorer, associated with some unix commands (in my case will be ClearCase commands).

Should I start learning to make a simple plugin for this?

Note: There are some ClearCase readily available plugins but all of them requires ClearCase client to be installed on windows machine (which I did) but our admins doesn't allow the windows clients to access version database for security purposes :)

So now I use putty console (Eclipse console) to check in/out files then edit them with Eclipse. Any chance to do'it once like I explain above?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No plugin possible, because ClearCase commands through an Eclipse plugin would be executed on your local machine, and not in the ssh session.

Those cleartool commands (checkout/checkin) must be executed where the view is started (ie on the unix remote server, where the ssh session is)